# Fallout New Vegas..where did my stuff go?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just finished the Zion expansion on Xbox 360. I started this several months ago and I can't remember where my stuff went that I had before starting it. I seem to remember it was confiscated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I played on PC but i got my items automaticaly when i exited that small cave where you "lost" your items.

How far did you get?Try fast travel somewhere far.

Other than that it can be a bug,or in case if you dropped items on floor instead getting them confiscated there is big chance of them just disapearing.

Comment: I already moved on to the latest expansion so it may be a while before I can report back. :-\